# Generating electricity from a magnet rotating around the Earth at its orbital velocity?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity, electricity, induction

As the title implies, can we induce electricity from a semi-perpetual moving magnet by gravity(at its orbital velocity?

I know there is no perpetual motion, but the magnet can fly for years without stopping, right?
And all we need is a source of motion to generate electricity, right?

So why can't we induce electricity from it like we do here on earth with the motion from fossil fuel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Lenz's Law, An electromagnetic induction will  be produced in the coil, and thus we get electricity. let the Power of the electricity generation be $P$.


But if you would calculate the Power of force of magnetic-magnetic interaction on the Magnet due to the current in the loop would be $-P$.


So even when you get energy, the "magnetic sattelite" would lose it's kinetic energy and fall on earth.


One of the most powerful Conservation law in physics is the Law of Conservation of Energy. It cannot be violated.